# Hide Certain <td> from source code retrieved from remote site based on keyword

Tags: php, html

I am using file get contents to get the source code of remote page then echo it to my page it

works well i want to hide certain `<td>` from the source code and prevent them from showing in

my page

I have two Code Snippet and want to integrate both

this code  `$('tr:has(td:contains("desktop"))').hide()`    which will

hide the td that have the work desktop

and this code

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http://remotesite/page.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $html;
?>
```

which will get the remote page source

how should both be written together .

Comment: If both having same structure. Just add your js code in script tag. Along with jQuery.

Comment: elements hidden using hide() will still be visible in the source code, I'm not sure if you are aware or if that matters. You can .remove() but even then someone with javascript disabled would see the elements

Comment: @Rikesh what do u mean by both?

Comment: @Jamil i doesn't matter if it still in the source what is important to me that this td doesn't appear in the client browser

Comment: Basically the jquery will operate on the text outputted by PHP as long as you execute the jquery after the php has loaded (ie, onDomReady)

Comment: @remyabel yes this is the point to make the jquery operate after the the code is retrived how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove that elements from PHP before outputting using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.domdocument.php) and [XPath](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.domxpath.php):

```
<?php

    $html = '<table>
    <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a desktop</td></tr>
    </table>';

    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $elements = $xpath->query("//td[contains(., 'desktop')]"); // search td's that contain 'desktop'

    foreach($elements as $el){
        $parent = $el->parentNode;
        //$parent->parentNode->removeChild($parent); // remove TR
        $parent->removeChild($el); // remove TD
    }

    echo $doc->saveHTML(); // save new HTML
?>
```

Comment: Great answer sir but the problem is it deleted all tr and td i have bo clue why?

Comment: I don't know, I've tested this and works. Try to output inside foreach the value to see if something is selected: `echo $el->nodeValue;`

Comment: here is the code i get through get file content from the remote page http://pastie.org/7897430 i want to remove only the tds that have download our free desktop app using

Comment: The problem is that HTML, isn't valid :(. For things to work correct HTML needs to be valid. I suggest you break up that HTML and them apply my code. See [this](http://codepad.org/58T1jgmP)

Comment: what do u mean by "break up that HTML" if you mean th reformat the html code ? this code i retrieve as is from the remote page